# Handle окна и java

Tags: windows, окно, java

Как средствами Java можно получить handle окна? И как, зная handle, можно закрыть это окно?

Comment: мне кажется в данной ситуации более уместным будет вопрос не "как" а "зачем"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нарыл вот такой вот способ, используя JNA:

```
User32 user32 = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
HWND foregroundHWND = user32.GetForegroundWindow();
user32.INSTANCE.PostMessage(foregroundHWND, User32.WM_CLOSE, new WinDef.WPARAM(), new WinDef.LPARAM());
```